# geodesic in terms of connection form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a unit speed curve in a surface M.

Let $E_1, E_2$ be an arbitrary tangent frame field on M.

Let $w_{12}(v)=\nabla_v E_1\cdot E_2$ for any tangent vector $v$.

How to prove that if $w_{12}(\alpha'(t))=0$, then $\alpha''$ is normal to M?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an arbitrary tangent frame field. It's an orthonormal frame field adapted to the curve $\alpha$, so $E_1=\alpha'$. Then note $\nabla_{\alpha'}E_1=\alpha''$, so to say $w_{12}(\alpha')=0$ is to say that the component of $\alpha''$ tangent to 
$M$ is $0$. (Note that because $E_1$ is everywhere a unit vector, the tangential component of its derivative is entirely in the $E_2$ direction.)

Comment: How can you prove that such $E_1$ always exist?

Comment: Along the curve, just take $E_1=\alpha'$ and $E_2$ normal to it in the surface. You can use a bit of local coordinate yoga to extend this all to a neighborhood of the curve. (There are local coordinates on the surface with $\alpha' = \partial/\partial x^1$, so define $E_1 = \partial/\partial x^1$ locally, and use the same argument.)

Comment: how can you prove that there are local coordinates on the surface with $\alpha'=d/dx^1$?

Comment: another question: If $\alpha$ is geodesic, then for ARBITRARY tangent frame field, does one have $w_{12}(\alpha')=0$?

Comment: The first is a standard theorem proved in a manifolds course. For the second, no, because if the frame itself twists as you move along the geodesic, you get a nonzero value.

Comment: Could you tell me some standard textbook that proves existence of a  tangent vector field adapted to the curve alpha?

Comment: I don't know your level or background. This requires understanding the flow of a vector field and the inverse function theorem. Standard books like Spivak's *Differential Geometry* (volume 1), Boothby, J. Lee's *Differentiable Manifolds* all have this result.